# Manipulate the order of elements with same count in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have 2 Lists named 'speciality' and 'count', which are part of a Dictionary 'P' . I Zip sorted both the 'Lists' on Descending order of 'count' List.

```
speciality = ['Cardiology' , 'Nephrology', 'ENT', 'Opthalmology' 'Oncology']
count = [2, 7, 9, 9, 1]

count, speciality = zip(*[[x, y] for x, y in sorted(zip(count, speciality), reverse=True)])

P = {'Speciliaty': speciality, 'Count': count}

print(P)
# {'Speciliaty': ('Opthalmology', 'ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'), 'Count': (9, 9, 7, 2, 1)}
```

Please notice, the elements 'Opthalmology' and 'ENT' has the same count 9.

But, after doing the Zip Sort. 
'Opthalmology' appeared before 'ENT' in the Output Tuple. In the Input the order is 'ENT' first then 'Opthalmology'.

Can we make the output like below:

```
P = {'Speciliaty': ('ENT', 'Opthalmology', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'), 'Count': (9, 9, 7, 2, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `key` in `sorted` to sort by count.

**Ex:**

```
speciality = ['Cardiology' , 'Nephrology', 'ENT', 'Opthalmology', 'Oncology']
count = [2, 7, 9, 9, 1]

count, speciality = zip(*[[x, y] for x, y in sorted(zip(count, speciality), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)])

P = {'Speciliaty': speciality, 'Count': count}
print(P)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Count': (9, 9, 7, 2, 1), 'Speciliaty': ('ENT', 'Opthalmology', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology')}
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, it worked. Can you please help me in understand x: X[0] will do in 'key'. I know about lambda, its a anonymous function.

Comment: if you print `print(sorted(zip(count, speciality)))` you can see the element[0] is count. I am using the lambda func to tell `sorted` to sort by element[0]